# Why is `object() > 0` True in Python?

Tags: python

```
In [32]: object() > 0
Out[32]: True
```

In fact, it's greater than any integer I've tried.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because Python 2.x tried to make available comparison between objects of different types (even if they do not make sense).

It was fixed on Python 3:

```
>>> object() > 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#320>", line 1, in <module>
    object() > 0
TypeError: unorderable types: object() > int()
```

The order used in Python 2.x:

```
None < Numbers < [Other types in alphabetical order]
```

Numbers are: `int`, `bool` and `float` but not `complex` because they can't be compared

Also, objects from old style classes (named `instance` objects) stay between `None` and `Numbers` for some odd reason.

Comment: It's true that, from a broad perspective, comparing different object types doesn't make sense, but it is nice to be able to sort heterogeneous types, and get a consistent ordering.

Comment: @JBernardo Could you please add a link to a related section in Python2.x documentation?

Comment: @Satoru.Logic Here's the [link](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons). Read the box "CPython implementation detail"

Answer (score 2):

It's comparing the **address of** the object. If you know C/C++, this is pointer arithmetic.

```
>>> object() < object()
True
>>> object() > object()
False
```

In the first example, the first object() happens to be allocated earlier in memory than the second one, hence it is 'less than' the other.

Regardless, you shouldn't be comparing pointers like this anyway. :)

Comment: You can confirm this by using the `id` function (http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id).  i.e.: id(object()) will return an integer.  That's the value being used for comparison to zero.

Comment: It does that for two objects of the same type that don't have a comparison defined, but for objects of different types, JBernardo's answer is correct.